# Does a github repo have a programmatic way to report what branches / releases are supported?

Tags: github, metadata, versioning

Is there a way to advertise and have consumers tell from the available REST APIs for [repos](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/) or their [branches](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/) or [releases](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/) that particular releases or major version branches are actively supported, maintenance support, or unsupported? Or application of some common support policy, like "*n*-2 major releases supported"?

This is towards writing automation that can alert, or even automate updating of dependent versions based on availability (e.g., there's a supported version to upgrade from my maintenance version).

Answer (score 0):

From the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) alone, no, as the notion of "support" is not a primary notion.

You could setup for a release naming convention, which would then allow the interpretation of the [repos/releases API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/).

Or describe that support explicitly in the `README` that you can get through the  [repos/contents API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-the-readme).

But any solution you might consider will involve some kind of convention/normalization.